# Struct pointers and their initialization

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struct in C as follows:

```c
typedef struct ENETPACKET_S {
    unsigned    n_rxcmd, n_txcmd;
    uint64_t    n_mac;  // 8 bytes unsigned or 64 bit
    unsigned    n_rxmiss, n_rxerr, n_rxcrc, n_txcol;
} ENETPACKET;
```

A pointer is being defined from the variable of this struct here below:

```
 static volatile ENETPACKET *const _net1 = ((ENETPACKET *)0x00500000);
```

I have two queries:

1. I understand pointers to a struct, but in the declaration of `_net1`, a pointer from a variable/object of a struct is being defined. I don't get that.
2. I am confused by the `((ENETPACKET *)0x00500000)` initialization of the `const` pointer, I don't understand what is being initialized here and the brackets and the `*` operator.

Comment: In a simple way, you can think `(ENETPACKET *)` as an `ENETPACKET` address variable type. So always think `ENETPACKET * ` as a symbol of variable type.

Comment: I see is a struct type alias with seven members, and a static volatile const pointer to one of those structures called `_net1` that is being hard-initialized to what appears to be a specific memory address (not uncommon for things like a virtual device driver, where real or virtual hardware maps IO regions to specific documented memory addresses). I'm not sure what you're talking about for (1).

Comment: And what is the address on computer devices? It means a long binary or hexadecimal number.  So converting a hexadecimal number to address variable type is referencing an address on computer.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks for clearing this up!
I missed the typedef part of the struct, so that clears up my point 1.
Also thanks for clearing up part 2 of my question as well. The value of the pointer is being initialized here, I was mixing it with values of some variable inside the struct being initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are working on an embedded device with possibly a micro-controller. In such systems, some peripherals can be configured/used by setting some registers. These registers can be read/written directly as it was memory available by your C program.

To give a small example of what it could looks like:

```
/* Control the PIN10 (input/output) */
/* The CONTROLLER of PIN10 is mapped at the address 0x00400000 */
static volatile uint8_t * const PIN10_CTRL = 0x00400000;

/* PIN10 control the output PIN of the MCU who is connected to a LED */
/* The STATUS of the PIN10 is mapped at the address 0x00400001 */
static volatile uint8_t * const PIN10 = 0x00400001;

*PIN10_CTRL = 0x1; /* Configure the PIN10 as a output PIN */

/* Blink the LED every second */
while (1)
{
  *PIN10 = 1;
   sleep(1);
  *PIN10 = 0;
   sleep(1);
}
```

If we consider your code now:

```
static volatile ENETPACKET *const _net1 = ((ENETPACKET *)0x00500000);
```

It *seems* like the networking interface of your micro-controller is putting the results of a `ENETPACKET` at the address `0x00500000`. This address is fixed and can probably be found in the user manual of your micro-controller.

The structure is *volatile* to prevent the compiler to do any assumption on the binary code he will generate. If the keyword *volatile* was omitted, you could have some optimizations applied on the program and the data to be out-of-date.

This address `0x00500000` is probably the address of an array of `N x ENETPACKET` packets.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing (working on an embedded device). The example code you wrote helped tons to understand the whole memory mapped concept of what my code is doing. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome! A small example is always helpful, the LED blinking example is a kind of a hello-world in the embedded world, because it's easy to take a PIN output and use it to understand what happen on resource-limited platforms. Typically, you connect that to an oscilloscope and toggle the PIN when the event you are debugging happen. This is quite handy.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question (which is a bit unclear), maybe consider how pointers to *simple* objects are declared and initialized:

```c
int i; // declares "i" as an "int"
int* p; // declares "p" as a "pointer to an int"
int* pi = &i; // declares "pi" as a pointer-to-int and initializes with address of "i"
```

Similarly, taking away the various qualifiers:

```c
ENETPACKET str; // Declares "str" as an actual ENETPACKET structure
ENETPACKET *pstr = &str; // pstr is a pointer-to-structure set to address of "str"
```

Now, the `const` qualifier **after the `*`** (and *before* the name) means that your code cannot (must not) change the value (address) assigned to the `_net1` variable in its initialization but that the actual data pointed to (i.e. the structure and the values of its members) **can** be changed: the pointer is `const`, not the referenced data; presumably, this is because the value assigned is a specific location in hardware.

For your second point, the `(ENETPACKET*)` preceding the constant is a [cast operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/cast); without it, your compiler will treat the `0x00500000` as an *integer* constant and generate a warning along the lines of the following (from clang-cl):

> warning : incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing
> 'volatile ENETPACKET *const' (aka 'volatile struct ENETPACKET_S
> *const') with an expression of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]

Adding the *explicit* cast tells the compiler: "Yes, I know the types are not the same but I know what I'm doing and want you to treat them as compatible." Use casts with caution!

The second (external) parentheses are actually not required but have been added by the author for clarity (which is a good thing); they *may* become important if the value used is changed from a constant/literal (as it is currently) to a more complex expression involving pointer arithmetic, or in the (perhaps more likely) case that a macro is used in place of the fixed literal.